# facebook like button using unobtrusive js in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-like, unobtrusive-javascript

I've just put a facebook like button on my rails app by adding the following tag into an html.erb page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=1419...&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="" send="" width="100" show_faces="" font="" layout="button_count" action="recommend"></fb:like>
```

And ... that works OK but I get a big white space on the page as the facebook sdk is loading. So, I thought I'd try putting this in my application.js file and running the function after the page is loaded. The only problem is that I can't get this to work at all :)

So far, I've kept the "fb-root" div in the html and I've placed the following function into application.js

```
$(function() {
    $('#fb-root').after('<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=1419...&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="" send="" width="100" show_faces="" font="" layout="button_count" action="recommend"></fb:like>');
});
```

However, this is not working for me and I can't figure out why (I'm a js newb). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured this out. First, I put the following tags in the html:

home.html.erb

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><div id="facebook">[Facebook]</div>
```

The important tag here is "fb-root" as that is what Facebook's javascript will look for. Then, in my js file I add this function:

application.js

```
// facebook recommend button                                                    
$(function() {
        likebutton =
            '<fb:like href="" send="" width="100" show_faces="" ' +
            'font="" layout="button_count" action="recommend">' +
            '</fb:like>';
        $.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', function() {
                FB.init({appId: 141936272547391,
                            status: true,
                            cookie: true,
                            xfbml: true
                            });
                $('#facebook').replaceWith(likebutton);
        });
    });
```

And, no more white box, if he client doesn't have JS enabled they just see "[Facebook]" and my code is nice and maintainable. :)

Answer (score 5):

You should load the javascript function [asynchronously](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Then once the javascript library has loaded, it will convert your fbml like button into the appropriate html iframe code.  If it is showing a white space until it loads, put the like button fbml code inside a div and style that div with css.

Here is a full example which doesn't have the issue you are talking about (I load the javascript library asynchronously, on a timed delay to simulate a slow load.  Notice that there is no white while the load button is loading.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#000">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:like href="http://stackoverflow.com" send="" width="100" layout="button_count" action="recommend"></fb:like>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    // delay to simulate slow loading of Facebook library - remove this setTimeout!!
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('loading fb');
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }, 3000);
  }());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's _almost_ what I'm looking for. But, I'd like to keep the javascript out of the html.erb file in keeping with the unobtrusive javascript convention. Thanks!

Comment: Just move the contents of that whole script to an external .js file then.